# Use Liferay Authentification to restrict directory listing on Tomcat?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, liferay, user-permissions

Is it possible to use Liferay Authentication in order to allow or deny access on a directory listing?

In my scenario Liferay is running under Tomcat. What I want is to restrict access on a specific directory and its content (lets say `localhost:8080/pdf/`). Currently each user is able to access the pdf-directory, which is not my intention.

May I use the current HTTP session?

-------- EDIT ---------

I will try to go more in detail: Under liferay tomcat I defined a new context as shown below.

```
<Context path="/pdfs" docBase="/Users/marco/Development/liferay/resources/pdfs/"
         crossContext="false" debug="0" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

The advantage of this is, I easly can access contents of "/pdfs". The disadvantage is, everybody can access "/pdfs".

The question is, how can I restrict access to "/pdfs"? My idea was to use Liferays authentication... but how? How can I restrict access to "/pdfs" to users currently logged into the Liferay application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best option is to implement the restrictions in the standard servlet filter, because this functionality is Tomcat-standard feature.

What do you mean using HTTP session? I guess you want to use the Liferay permision-checker system to avoid listing directories, right?

Best regards,
Jorge

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The topic is still relevant.

Comment: Using the Liferay permision-checker system is completely new to me? I will give it a try ... later. Thank you.

Comment: I refined my question (see original question above).

Answer (score 0):

With setting the context you bypassed Liferay.

I would suggest another approach. Instead of defining docBase I would store dokument in Liferay Document Library. You have much better control over the content's permissions.

```
DLFileEntryServiceUtil.addFileEntry(...)
```